# Twitter Bootstrap: how to put a label for radio and checkbox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a TB way to introduce radio and checkbox options? For example:

**Foo Options Introduction:**

- Foo One
- Foo Two

Basically, something similar to `<label>`'s role for `<input>`, etc. The following is the code for 2 radio options, but without the "label":

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio" for="foo_foo1">
            <input type="radio" name="foo" value="foo1" id="foo_foo1">
            Foo One
        </label>
        <label class="radio" for="foo_foo2">
            <input type="radio" name="foo" value="foo2" id="foo_foo2">
            Foo Two
        </label>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Prefer a TB solution.

Comment: FYI:  if you have `<label><input /></label>`, the for/id attributes are redundant.  They're only necessary if the input appears outside of the label that it belongs to.

Comment: Good catch. I do need that for some JS, though. But you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `<fieldset>` with a `<legend>`?

As in the first example here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Or an information alert?  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts

Comment: No. `<legend>` is probably semantically incorrect, plus I'm already using it in the form to introduce what the sub-set of the form is. Alert is a hackish solution.

Comment: Why would it be semantically incorrect?  Fieldsets are for grouping form controls, and they're allowed to be nested.  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/fieldset

Comment: Yes, grouping of related form controls. I see a radio (and all it's options) as one control. It's a subjective thing, I suppose.

Comment: Also, valid HTML does not mean it's semantically correct. It's valid to use `<b>`, but that's not semantically correct.

Comment: When you said you were already using fieldset/legend, it sounded like you were afraid to use it for the radios because you already had one elsewhere.  If you still have reservations about using fieldset/legend here, you can always use a `select` instead, which is just a different way to present the same behavior you would get from a radio.  Depending on how the radios are presented, users may find selects less confusing.

Comment: `select` is indeed an option. However, this is really about seeing if there is already an elegant way to handle this in TB.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want to have a label one level above the radio buttons. Like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="foo_controls">Foo Options Introduction:</label>
    <div id="foo_controls" class="controls">
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="foo" value="foo1" id="foo_foo1">
            Foo One
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="foo" value="foo2" id="foo_foo2">
            Foo Two
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Bootstrap 3 you have to use [checkbox-inline and radio-inline](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) classes on the label.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
```